# npm install the exact package version specified in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, npm-install

Currently, If I run `npm install`, it installs the updated version of already installed packages. How can I install the exact version as specified in the `package.json` file?

Comment: how have you specified the version in the `package.json`? there is a modifier for fixed version.

Comment: My bad, `package.json` had  versions specified as  `^version`. I just assumed this how to versions. Will remove the `^` modifier. Thanks!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

That behavior is really driven by the one specifying the versions in the package.json. If the version number looks like "1.0.0", without any other symbols, the exact version (1.0.0) should be installed.

So what you could do is simply modify the package.json and run a `npm install` then. Be sure to clear out the node_modules directory before you do that.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

Comment: Please note that there is still one issue with all subdependencies. Even if you specify strict versions for direct dependencies, the is no guarantee that those in turn will not trigger the installation of something new when it will be released.

Comment: I can't believe this is the only solution. It's very important for those creating packages to test with the lowest possible number. I'm considering creating a separate `package-min.json` file and using that as the `package.json` in CI

Answer (score 123):

By default npm installs packages using ^ which means any version in the same major range, you can switch this behaviour by using --save-exact

```
// npm
npm install --save --save-exact react

// yarn
yarn add --exact react
```

I created a blog post about this if anyone is looking for this in the future.

https://www.dalejefferson.com/articles/2018-02-04-how-to-save-exact-npm-package-versions/

Comment: Also, for both npm and yarn `-E` is the short form of `--save-exact` / `--exact`

Comment: Is exact version necessary or is the same major range ok

Comment: Is there any way to make this behavior default across all installations with `npm`?

Comment: yes, there is: `npm config set save-exact=true` or you can add `save-exact=true` to your .npmrc manually

Answer (score 48):

You can also open `package.json` and change value for the package you want to remain exact. From `"vue": "^2.6.10"` to `"vue": "2.6.10"`. Notice the lack of `^` sign in front of the version number.

Comment: the `^` signifies that npm can install any version greater than or equal to 2.x.x, where x is 6.10, e.g. 2.6.11 or 2.7.0, etc.