# how to rollback angularfire2 4.0, back to angularfire 2 2.0?

Tags: angular, ionic2, angularfire, hybrid-mobile-app, angularfire2

I updated to angularfire2 4.0, how can I rollback to the previous version as many of my application work on angularfire2 2.0 and I want to stick to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest and easiest way is by specifying the version in the command itself.

**Command**

```
npm install angularfire2@2.0.0-alpha.17 --save
```

**How NPM works with versions**

By adding `@2.0.0-alpha.17` to the package name you tell NPM to install version **2.0.0-alpha.17**. And by adding the flag `--save`, you tell NPM to also save this version to your package.json.

**How to view previous package versions?**

You can can ask NPM to show you a list of previous versions/releases by using the command:

```
npm view angularfire2 versions
```

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly add the version you want to your `package.json` and do `npm install`

[npm install the exact package version specified in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003470/npm-install-the-exact-package-version-specified-in-package-json)