# How to use create-react-app with an older React version?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

When using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) with [custom-react-scripts](https://github.com/kitze/custom-react-scripts) I always end up with React 16 (latest) installed. Is there a way to create a new project with an older version, like React 15?

Comment: You can specify version of package in package.json. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json

Comment: I directly changed package.json to version 15.6.2, and to my suprise it just worked! Make it an answer, let me upvote you.

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help you. If you are satisfied with solution, you can just remove the post as I would mark it as duplicate anyways. Have a good day :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install the exact package version specified in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003470/npm-install-the-exact-package-version-specified-in-package-json)

Answer (score 176):

If you're here because of react v18, and you want to go down to the previous non-change breaking version, here's what i did:

in your `package.json` replace:

```
"react": "^18.0.0"
"react-dom": "^18.0.0"
```

with

```
"react": "^17.0.2"
"react-dom": "^17.0.2"
```

Then go to your entry file `index.js`
At the top, replace:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
```

with

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Still in your `index.js` file, replace:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

with

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

- Delete your `node_modules` and run `yarn install` or `npm install`
- After installation, run `yarn start` or `npm run start`
- Enjoy

Comment: I received errors while trying to install a new package. To fix, I also had to change `@testing-library/react` to version 12 in my package.json. I.e.: 
"@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0" and "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.0.0"

Comment: on unix system you can run: `APP_NAME='my-app' && npx create-react-app $APP_NAME && cd $APP_NAME && npm install react@17 react-dom@17 @testing-library/react@12 @types/react@17 @types/react-dom@17 @testing-library/react@12 @testing-library/user-event@12`. Than you only need to update the index.tsx file as described above.

Comment: Is react-scripts: 5.0.1 compatible with react 17? or do I have to downgrade it to version 4 too?

Answer (score 22):

It seems that you can just go ahead and use it to generate a React 16 app, then edit package.json and run `npm i` (or `npm install`; `npm i` is just a shortcut).

I just left the `react-scripts` version at the latest version and only changed the versions of `react` and `react-dom`, and it worked:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "react-scripts": "1.0.14"
},
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^15.6.1",
  "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
},
```

Comment: make sure to delete node_modules folder before doing 'npm install'

Answer (score 17):

Complementing the answers described above, after all the manipulation, I had to update this libs(for TS template) :

```
"@testing-library/react": "^12.1.1",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.5.0"
```

Answer (score 8):

- When You Using

```js
npx create-react-app app-name
```

it will always install latest react packages. Then, in `react 18.2.0`, It is some of different about previous version.

- If you want to **downgrade** your **current react** version to **previous version** of react, Try These **5 Steps**.

1. You go to your folder file structure and **delete** both `package-lock.json` ( `yarn.lock` for yarn) file and `node_modules` file.
2. After you go to your `package.json` file and change and edit these dependencies :

```js
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
```

to

```js
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
```

in your `package.json` **dependencies** file like this.

3. After go to Your `index.js` file change,

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
```

to

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

4. After change your `index.js` file and change below part of index file.

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

to

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

5. Finally, You can open the `terminal` and run

if you are using npm -->> `npm install`

and after the installing part you can run app `npm start`.

or

if you are using yarn -->> `yarn install`

and after the installing part you can run app `yarn start`.

--Thank You--
**--Happy Coding--**

Comment: Bookmarked, thanks! Needed to get a legacy 16.8* version of react going. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

If you already created with `React 18`, you can downgrade version 18 to previous verions of react with a few steps.
You will need to do modifications in two files which are `package.json` and `index.js` . You should delete  also `node_modules`

**Step 1**

Your `index.js` probably looks like this now

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

You should change import of `ReactDOM` and cancel `const root` line

New code of `index.js` should be like this

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Step 2**

Go to your `package.json` file and update desired react version in dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    ...
  },
```

**Step 3**

Delede your node_modules and If you are using **npm** do `npm i`. If you are using **yarn** do `yarn install`. After this step you are good to run app with `npm start` or `yarn start`.

**Step 4 (OPTIONAL: If you are still having problems but I do not recommend doing it)**

Delete your `package-lock.json` (for **npm**) or `yarn.lock` file (for **yarn**) and start back from **Step 3**

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem, especially with the new create-react-app v18. All I did was to delete my `package-lock.json` file and also my `node_modules` folder. I edited `package.json` afterwards, replaced react-dom and react with the version that I want as below:

```json
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
```

Finally, I installed my packages again using `npm install`

Comment: I think there were some breaking changes, and the CRA index (and maybe other files) were updated to the new way to do things in v18 -- haven't tried yet, but might need to undo the changes described here https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html

Answer (score 3):

1. First create react app
   npx create-react-app .
   (. Means current file)
2. [Delete node_modules & package-lock.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxaH2.png)
3. 

```js
 "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "firebase": "^8.8.0",
    "firebase-login": "^1.0.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.16.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-currency-format": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
```

As per require version of react & react-dom along with other required

4. Run command in bash/terminal
   npm install

(it will download all data as per package.json)

5. (optional)
   In project src/index.js

```js
ReactDOM.render(`enter code here`
  <React.StrictMode>
  <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getE1ementById( 'root' )
);
 
Replace this with 
 
 
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

This.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to install npm in your system Then
For Create react app you have to run below command

> **sudo npm init react-app my-app --scripts-version 1.1.5**
>
> **cd  my-app**
>
> **sudo npm install --save react@16.0.0**
>
> **sudo npm install --save react-dom@16.0.0**

It worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Usually using `sudo` isn't a good idea for a folder containing an app

Comment: this worked for me in ubuntu 20.04. CRA kept crashing but this one launched in a minute

Answer (score 1):

Already some good answars, but adding one new one it might help someone

1. Delete node modules, package-lock.json, yarn.lock.
2. In dependency section of package.json

   ```
    "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "firebase": "^8.8.0",
    "firebase-login": "^1.0.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^0.1.6",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-currency-format": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
   ```

   },
3. In index.js

   ```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import "./index.css";
    import App from "./App";
    import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>,
      document.getElementById("root")





   );
   ```
4. npm cache clean --force
5. npm install / yarn install

**OPTIONAL**

Additilnally if you want to add some more dependencies or any exception may occur the below steps may help.

**INSTALL REACT SCRIPTS :**

```
npm install react-scripts
```

**INSTALL WEBVITALS:**

```
npm install --save-dev web-vitals
yarn add web-vitals --dev
```

**INSTALL ENZYME:**

```
npm i --save-dev enzyme enzyme-adapter-react-16
```

**INSTALL JEST:**

```
npm install --save-dev jest
yarn add --dev jest
yarn add --dev babel-jest babel-core
```

Answer (score 0):

It's WORKED for me..

1. Just uninstall the react 18 and install the react 17.

Run This Command

```
npm uninstall react
```

2.Then install React 17.0.2 Just run this command.

```
npm install react@17.0.2
```

3. For installing react-dom version 17.0.2  run this command.

   `npm install --save  react-dom@17.0.2`

- Enjoy and Add Comment if it's worked for you

Answer (score 0):

you can try the command with respective combination of react and react-dom

npm i react@latest react-dom@latest
npm i react@18.2.0 react-dom@17.2.0

This way you can install the react and react dom and get their respective version by react-dom

npm view react version
npm view react-dom version

Answer (score -3):

Specify your script version while create project

**sudo npm init react-app appname --scripts-version 1.0.13**

its working for me