# How can I use create-react-app for React version 16.x.x with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I need to run up a sandbox React app with version 16 and typescript.

Does anyone know how to do that as `npx create-react-app --template=typescript blah` now uses React 17?

*Update*

As suggested in the comments I've attempted to install with this:

`npm init react-app migration-calculator-npm-demo --scripts-version 3.4.4`

and

`npm init react-app migration-calculator-npm-demo --template typescript --scripts-version 3.4.4`

`3.4.4` looks like the last version of `react-scripts` since before the major update.

Unfortunately, I'm getting errors with both.

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1088
> throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'cra-template'

and

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1088
> throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'cra-template-typescript'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use create-react-app with an older React version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566830/how-to-use-create-react-app-with-an-older-react-version)

Comment: I'll see if that does the trick, cheers.

Comment: @radovix Do you know what version of `react-scripts` should be used now?

Comment: Not really. Sorry.

Comment: Have you tried to install the app like you would normally and then change the react version in the package.json, then re install the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

`npx create-react-app blah` uses the version you have installed. If you have react package version 16 installed, then it will use version 16.
You can also run a specific react-script version:
Example: `sudo npm init react-app my-app --scripts-version 3.4.0`, [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566830/how-to-use-create-react-app-with-an-older-react-version)

Comment: Do you know what version of react-scripts I should use? `1.1.5` looks old to me.

Comment: 3.4.0 should work. You can also try 3.3.1.
The version you used (3.4.4) was released 2 weeks ago?

Comment: I tried these and more the other day, I got the errors above. 1.1.5 works but does not support typescript templates.

Comment: Hmm.. did you try to:
1.) Deinstall create-react-app globally: `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
2.) Try again to create the app: `npm init react-app my-app --scripts-version 3.4.0`

Comment: I just tried that, the same issue. Did you have any luck with the command? Maybe somethings up with my npm.

Comment: @Amel, I tried your solution and I got React 18, I think the OP was asking how to do it where you get React 16.

Answer (score -2):

I think this will help you to create react app with typescript.

```
 npx create-react-app my-app --scripts-version 16.XX.XX --template  typescript
```

Comment: The `react-scripts` versions are different from the `react` and `react-dom` versions.
Here you can find the list of the current versions of `react-scripts`:
[react-scripts versions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts)

Comment: @Sagar Kumar, Your answer does not work as there is no react-scripts version 16.