# how can i create new react app with node 13.6 on windows 7

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows-7, create-react-app, npx

I installed node v 13.6 on my pc and when I want create new react app with node , the terminal error says: Create react app requires node 14 . but I can't install node 14 on windows 7, and unfortunately can't upgrade windows
how can I create a new react app with v 13.6 of node? or install v 14 or higher of node on windows 7?
I really need to solve this problem

Comment: You need to look into installing an older version of react - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64664196/how-can-i-use-create-react-app-for-react-version-16-x-x-with-typescript. You will need to find out what versions of React support Node 13.6 I believe everything before 18 does.

Comment: thank you for response dear, but version of react isnt my problem. in beginning i cant create app! after creating, i can change version of react to older, but first how can create the app?

Comment: You won't be able to install the wrong version, you need to install the correct version from the beginning. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66749952/create-react-app-with-an-older-version-of-node