# I'm installing redux form library and it keep on showing these errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-deployment

[image: this is the image]

and my node version is v16.1.0.
And and tried re-installing the node but it is still showing the errors. i cleared the cache as well

Comment: Please reproduce error messages **as text** in your answer so that others with the same problem can use search engines to find answers. ***Images can't be indexed.***

Comment: ok i'll do it next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your project is configured to use React 17, but redux-form depends on React 16.

If you want to play it safe, downgrade to React 16. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566830/how-to-use-create-react-app-with-an-older-react-version) for more info.