# How to use create-react-app to install previous react.js versions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I want to use one **previous version** of react (16.0.0) but couldn't find any way to install previous version by using **"create react app"**.

One answer on this topic was posted in stackoverflow that says that I need to install the latest version by using "create react app" then I need to `edit package.json file` and specify my desired version (react & react-dom) and run `npm install` command.

But couldn't get my desired version. It's still the current version (17.0.2). Can anyone fix the issue please?

Comment: This might be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566830/how-to-use-create-react-app-with-an-older-react-version

Comment: you can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566830/how-to-use-create-react-app-with-an-older-react-version)

Answer (score 1):

delete .lock file and then try installing packages