# how to install the react app on my folder without getting an error

Tags: reactjs, npm

PS D:\React Projects\First project> npx create-react-app first-project
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-06-21T06_31_47_876Z-debug-0.log
PS D:\React Projects\First project>

i need to install the react app on my folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use create-react-app to install previous react.js versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67950810/how-to-use-create-react-app-to-install-previous-react-js-versions)