# Error when run in command line "npm install firebase"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\CarInventory>npm install firebase
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: 3d-react-carousal@5.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @restart/hooks@0.4.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@restart/hooks
npm ERR!     @restart/hooks@"^0.4.0" from @restart/ui@1.2.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@restart/ui
npm ERR!       @restart/ui@"^1.2.0" from react-bootstrap@2.3.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-bootstrap
npm ERR!         react-bootstrap@"^2.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     @restart/hooks@"^0.4.6" from react-bootstrap@2.3.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-bootstrap
npm ERR!       react-bootstrap@"^2.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.14.0" from @restart/ui@1.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@restart/ui
npm ERR!     @restart/ui@"^1.2.0" from react-bootstrap@2.3.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-bootstrap
npm ERR!       react-bootstrap@"^2.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   15 more (@testing-library/react, prop-types-extra, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.2" from 3d-react-carousal@5.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/3d-react-carousal
npm ERR!   3d-react-carousal@"^5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.2" from 3d-react-carousal@5.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/3d-react-carousal
npm ERR!     3d-react-carousal@"^5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-07T06_10_59_271Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: offtopic *"3d-react-carousal"* carous**a**l... lol

Comment: When asking questions, please provide details on what you are trying to accomplish, what solutions you have already attempted, and what steps might be required for us to reproduce the problem. This is not enough information for us to solve your problem.

Comment: You'll see this happening a lot at the moment. Packages have their React peer dependency set to v16 or v17, but not 18. Sometimes its because it would introduce a breaking change, or the package maintainers haven't got around to updating the package.json. I would suggest either finding a way to use a previous version of CRA, or going to the package repo on Github and logging an issue.

Comment: [This may help.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71908461/1377002).

Answer (score 1):

try `npm install firebase --legacy-peer-deps`