# create-react-app always throws babel error

Tags: javascript, node.js

Every time I create a create-react-app project it throws this error:

```
The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "babel-loader": "8.0.4"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of babel-loader was detected higher up in the tree:

  /Users/dalegrant/Desktop/hyberchat-dashboard/client/node_modules/babel-loader (version: 8.0.5)
```

I have tried downgrading to 8.0.4,

I've tried installing 8.0.5

I've even made sure all my dependencies for babel rely on a 8.0.5!

I have no idea what to do from here as the error persists for every create react app I now build!

This must be a common problem, does anybody have an idea on how to get around this?!

Comment: According to warning message- You don't have to install babel-loader. If you already did,  uninstall or just remove node modules directory. remove this from the package manager. Create React App will automatically add all required dependencies

Comment: `I've tried installing 8.0.5` that was a mistake...

Comment: PPB i tried that many many times and then resorted to installing it, Jonas

Comment: @Sparlarva start by installing [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/) - it's much easier to [manage peer dependencies](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/managing-dependencies/) using yarn rather than npm in my experience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your machine user folder there is a `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` remove them using `rm -rf User/node_modules` and `rm -rf User/package-lock.json` after that delete `node_module` directory and `pack-lock.json` file in your project run `npm install` again then it's works

Answer (score 1):

Remove the babel-loader package (also globally):

```
  npm uninstall babel-loader
  npm uninstall babel-loader -g
```

Then run `create-react-app` again, it should install the correct dependency.

If you use the babel-loader somewhere else, [pin the dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003470/npm-install-the-exact-package-version-specified-in-package-json) there to ensure this problem does not happen again.

Comment: Hi I'm just about to try this, when you say 'pin the dependency' what does that mean? could babel-loader being installed in some directories/projects affect others?

Comment: @sparlarva yes, if installed globally.

Comment: It wasn't installed globally, I removed it locally from all 4 of my applications anyway and now i'm trying to create a new one, I have a feeling the same problem will crop up

Comment: I don't have it installed globally, I have the same error creating a new react app!

Answer (score 0):

you probably installed `node_modules` in your main folders before.  Search for them and remove.
In my case i have installed `node_modules` on my Home folder. When i removed files from this directory problem disapeared