# Preventing package.json from updating packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I wanted to know if there is any clean way of preventing package.json file from updating to latest versions of the dependencies that it contains.

The reason I don't want them to update is because of I need to frequently run few scripts with certain libraries the project contains and if the libraries get updated to latest versions, then I may not be able to validate my tests if some additional transitive dependencies are present.

Please note: I am not using npm update in any case, but I do use npm install.

Comment: You mean that was `package-lock.json` does/is for ? npm install does not update any package. It just does what the name say, its install a new package.

Comment: Make sure to include version of the packages in the package.json. Also when you `npm install <package>@1.2.3 --save` make sure to include the version. It should not update automaticaly when the version is specified.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install the exact package version specified in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003470/npm-install-the-exact-package-version-specified-in-package-json)

Comment: @Stebeber Yes, it's working now as expected.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41003507/4236831

You can specify the exact version in your `package.json` file.

A more detailed overview of managing the versions of your dependencies can be found here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies

Comment: Thank you very much, just removing the caret symbol helped.!